# Events timetable

Tags: algorithm

I have the following task. There is the 24-hours timetable. And there are some events with fixed length. I have a new event with predefined length ( for example 1 hour and 25 minutes ). The task is to know - how many times I can insert this task during the day (this task must not   intersect other events.

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried trivial solution, but now I search for special algos.

Comment: There are not really any algorithms to consider, since already naive algorithm accomplishes the task in O(n) :))). But wait, there might be one thing - sacrifice memory for performance, maintain the counts as an array for each free period, and when your daily schedule changes, only update those free periods, that changed. Not much to gain there, however, unless your day has million sections like DNA :)))

Answer (score 1):

our question might be considered a bit simplistic,
so let the answer be simplistic, too (in Ruby):

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
DAY_START = 0
DAY_END = 24*60
# now, busy periods as array of size-2 arrays:
BUSY_PERIODS = [[9*60, 9*60+30], [18*60+30, 20*60]]
ADDITIONAL_EVENT_LENGTH = 1*60 + 25   # that is, 1 hour and  25 minutes
# in this simple program,
# time will be expressed as a number of minutes of the day
# for more advanced use, try to use "Time" class

# now let define a function to compute the list of free periods
# from a given list of busy periods:
def compute_free_periods( list_of_events )
  # at the begining of the calculation, our whole day is assumed free:
  free_periods = Array[ [ DAY_START, DAY_END] ]
  # now, one by one, let us take away the busy periods:
  list_of_events.each_with_object free_periods do | busy_period, free_periods |
    # we use 'each_with_object' version of 'each' enumerator
    # list of free_periods is passed in as an external object
    # so that we can gradually take each busy period away from it

    # let us first note the end time for the last free period
    # ( [-1] refers to the last element of the list of free periods,
    # subsequent [1] to the second element of the size-2 array )
    last_free_period_end = free_periods[-1][1]

    # and now, let us split this last free period into two by the
    # current busy period (busy periods assumed non-overlapping and
    # sorted in ascending order)

    # first, end time of the last free period is set to the beginning
    # of the busy period that we consider in this iteration:
    free_periods[-1][1] = busy_period[0]

    # then, additional free period is appended to the list of
    # free periods usind << operator, starting when the busy period ends:
    free_periods << [ busy_period[1], last_free_period_end ]
  end
end

# now, let us use the function we just defined:
free_periods = compute_free_periods( BUSY_PERIODS )

# Now, for each free period we will count how many times we can stuff
# in the desired additional event:
free_period_capacities = free_periods.map { |free_period|
  # we are using map function for this, which will return
  # an array of the same length as free_periods, having
  # performed prescribed modifications on each element:

  # first, we calculate how many minutes a free period has
  period_length = free_period[1] - free_period[0]
  # then, we will use whole-number division to get the number
  # of additional events that can fit in:
  period_length / ADDITIONAL_EVENT_LENGTH
  # (in Ruby, whole number division is the default behavior of / operator)
}

# and finally, we sum up the free period capacities for our new event:
total_events_possible = free_period_capacities.reduce( :+ )
# (summing is done elegantly by using reduce function with + operator)

# the last remaining thing we can do to consider program finished is to
puts total_events_possible # print the result on the screen
```

If you take out comments and shorten it, then the program becomes quite short:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
DAY_START, DAY_END = 0, 24*60
BUSY_PERIODS = [[9*60, 9*60+30], [18*60+30, 20*60]]
ADDITIONAL_EVENT_LENGTH = 1*60 + 25

def compute_free_periods( list_of_events )
  free_periods = Array[ [ DAY_START, DAY_END] ]
  list_of_events.each_with_object free_periods do | busy_period, free_periods |
    last_free_period_end = free_periods[-1][1]
    free_periods[-1][1] = busy_period[0]
    free_periods << [ busy_period[1], last_free_period_end ] end
end

free_periods = compute_free_periods( BUSY_PERIODS )
free_period_capacities = free_periods.map { |free_period|
  period_length = free_period[1] - free_period[0]
  period_length / ADDITIONAL_EVENT_LENGTH }
puts ( total_events_possible = free_period_capacities.reduce( :+ ) )
```

You see, there is not so much of an algorithm. Just plain coding. Pick up
eg. Ole Foul Zed's textbook [Learn Ruby The Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/) and start
reading from Exercise 0 to the end. Or, you can go for some other language,
such as [Python](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/). Ole Zed has teaching talent. If you appreciate the
experience, don't forget to buy it as ebook.